# Docker - Process not starting at boot

Tags: docker, containers, grafana

I am containerizing the latest version of grafana and want to start the `grafana-process` when the container starts and then use it in my K8S (kubernetes) cluster.

My Dockerfile looks like :

```
FROM armdocker/baseimages/rhel:7-20161207
MAINTAINER xxxxxxxx

ENV GRAFANA_VERSION_MAJOR=4 GRAFANA_VERSION_MINOR=4 GRAFANA_VERSION_PATCH=3-1
ENV GRAFANA_VERSION=${GRAFANA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${GRAFANA_VERSION_MINOR}.${GRAFANA_VERSION_PATCH}

RUN yum clean all && yum install -y unzip tar

RUN curl  -f -L -o grafana-${GRAFANA_VERSION}.x86_64.rpm https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/grafana-releases/release/grafana-${GRAFANA_VERSION}.x86_64.rpm && \
    yum localinstall grafana-${GRAFANA_VERSION}.x86_64.rpm -y

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/grafana-server start"]
```

Building the Dockerfile is successful and returns no errors.

When I try to run this image, I get the ERROR.

```
docker run -dit -p 3000:3000 armdocker/proj/grafana:1.0.5
471b2acb964caad69bbb78831a59ee9d2b27997911b5b104b0057ddc957d1101
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 471b2acb964caad69bbb78831a59ee9d2b27997911b5b104b0057ddc957d1101: [8] System error: exec: "/etc/init.d/grafana-server start": stat /etc/init.d/grafana-server start: no such file or directory
```

This seems to be very weird since I am installing the RPM first (which makes the file `/etc/init.d/grafana-server` ) and then I am trying to start the process as my `ENTRYPOINT`

I then tried

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/grafana-server start"]
```

This also results in the same ERROR `/etc/init.d/grafana-server start: no such file or directory`

I then tried using the `systemctl` command :

```
docker run -dit -p 3000:3000 armdocker/proj/grafana:1.0.6
bfd492c75a0f4c284fc0fdbd5a590f0155f6f67bcb4834e144f344bb789546f3
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container bfd492c75a0f4c284fc0fdbd5a590f0155f6f67bcb4834e144f344bb789546f3: [8] System error: exec: "/bin/systemctl start grafana-server.service": stat /bin/systemctl start grafana-server.service: no such file or directory
```

I am out of ideas as to what am I doing wrong to have a container with a started grafana process.

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/grafana-server"]`
`CMD ["start"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're running your own systemd daemon inside of the container (I don't recommend this, it creates lots of issues), you shouldn't be trying to start the process with a `systemctl` or `/etc/init.d` command. Containers are not a VM, they are a method to run an application within their own namespace. And when that application exits, so do your container. When your application is something like a `systemctl` start command, your container will exit the moment that systemctl command returns, which isn't useful it you were hopping it would stay up for the duration of the grafana process running.

Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, I'd recommend you look at how grafana themselves packages their docker container. Specifically their run.sh ends with:

```
exec gosu grafana /usr/sbin/grafana-server      \
  --homepath=/usr/share/grafana                 \
  --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini             \
  cfg:default.log.mode="console"                \
  cfg:default.paths.data="$GF_PATHS_DATA"       \
  cfg:default.paths.logs="$GF_PATHS_LOGS"       \
  cfg:default.paths.plugins="$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" \
  "$@"
```

Their repo is over at https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use the [docker-systemctl-replacement script](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) and register it as the main CMD of the image. It will check out the *.service scripts to know how to start and stop a service (without the help of a systemd daemon). So if the Grafana guys change their startup scenario then your builds will continue to work. ;)